# Haskell - "Type error in application": "unification would give infinite type"

Tags: haskell

I'm beginning work with Haskell, but this equality check I'm attempting to make isn't working out.

I have a function, `countLetter a [b] c`, where `a` is a char, `b` is a list of chars and `c` is an int. (The type declarations passed through fine.) But I run into problems with this expression:

```
if a == head(b)
```

Gives me the following message:

```
Type error in application

*** Expression     : a == head b
*** Term           : a
*** Type           : [a]
*** Does not match : a
*** Because        : unification would give infinite type
```

My code in full, if it's needed, is this:

```
countLetter :: char -> [char] -> int

countLetter a [b] c = if null b

                       then []
                       else
                       if a == head(b)
                       then countLetter a tail(b) c+1
                    else
                    countLetter head(b) tail(b) c
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, types in Haskell start with capital letters. If you use identifiers starting with lower case letters in a type signature, they're interpreted as type variables. So your type `char -> [char] -> int` is the same as `a -> [a] -> b`, which is not a sensible type for your function. Your want `Char -> [Char] -> Int`.

Secondly `[]` is not a valid value of type `Int`. Fixing your type signature should produce an error message that tells you this in less ambiguous terms.

It should then also tell you that `null b` is a type error because `b` is of type `Char` (the second argument of your function is of type `[Char]` and you've matched it against the pattern `[b]`, binding `b` to the single `Char` contained in that list) and `null` takes a list, not a Char, as its argument.

To clarify the last point a bit:

The second argument to your function is a list. By writing `[b]` in your parameter list, you're matching that argument against the pattern `[b]`. In other words writing `countLetter a [b] c = blabla` is the same as writing:

```
countLetter a theList c =
    case theList of
        [b] -> blabla
```

So you're saying: "the second argument to the function must be a list with one single element and that element shall be called `b`". That is not what you want to be saying. What you want to be saying is "the second argument to the function (which, incidentally, is a list) shall be called `b`". For that you simply writie `countLetter a b c = blabla`.

Parameters of type list don't have to be denoted any differently than other types of parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I didn't know about the capitalisation, so that's a big help.
I got the error with `null b` just as you said. I had thought that b would be a list, but I seem to be wrong. Could you tell me how I can represent b as a list properly?

I'm also uncertain about how to end a list if I can't use []. My past experience has been with Core Haskell, and while I've been doing my reading, I still don't know any other ways to end a list.

Comment: @SamOfloinn I expanded my answer. Hopefully that clears everything up.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting to know. Thank you again!
I'll try to resolve the next issue I get by myself for a while. Have a good night!

Answer (score 2):

Another error you will encounter is this:

```
countLetter head(b) tail(b) c
```

This is, by the rules, the same as

```
countLetter head b tail b c
```

i.e. you call your countLetter function with 5 arguments, when it only takes 3 (according to the first equation) or 2 (according to your type signature). (This is another point the compiler will be *very* unhappy with.)

You probably want this:

```
countLetter (head b) (tail b) c
```

Likewise:

```
countLetter a tail(b) c+1
```

is the same as

```
(countLetter a tail b c) + 1
```

but you probably want:

```
countLetter a (tail b) (c+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the other answers, which provide ways to fix your function, you may want to consider writing this in a more compositional style.  Specifically, look for ways you could write a function by building up other, standard functions.  Suppose you have a function that will remove everything that isn't equal to the test letter from a list.

```
myFilter :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char
myFilter = ...
```

After using `myFilter`, you'd be left with a list with only the element you're checking for.  At this point, you can just use `length` to get the length of the list:

```
countLetter :: Char -> [Char] -> Int
countLetter a b = length $ myFilter a b
```

So now you just need to define `myFilter`, which can be done with the standard Prelude function `filter`

```
myFilter a b = filter (==a) b
```

For a function this small, creating our own definition is hardly worth it, as you can just write

```
countLetter a b = length $ filter (== a) b
```

Now, define this in ghci to see what type it finds for the function `countLetter`

```
Prelude> let countLetter a b = length $ filter (== a) b
Prelude> :t countLetter
countLetter :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
```

No `Char` in sight!  The implementation doesn't depend on the elements being letters, only that they can be compared for equality (this is true of your approach also).  So ghci reflects that in the calculated type.  But you can see that this is exactly the type you want by substituting `Char` for `a`.

Many functional programmers tend to find this approach, i.e. building functions by composing smaller parts, particularly easy to reason about, so it can be quite common.  Especially when working with lists, you might want to see if you can write an implementation using so-called higher-order functions, such as `map`, `filter`, or a fold, instead of using recursion.  Sometimes recursion is the clearest way, but I expect you will frequently find function composition to be a better approach.